# How can I invoke callback while login in Google in .net core?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I am coding a third-party login-in with Google.

Here is the tutorial of Microsoft:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins?view=aspnetcore-3.0

I did what it said by using the `Secret Manager` and `AddAuthentication`

When I click the Login button on the website, it will redirect to google login successfully.

Now the next step is the invoke the callback. However, I don't know how to invoke it after login.

The tutorial of Microsoft only shows these two class:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.google.googleoptions?view=aspnetcore-2.2

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.remoteauthenticationoptions.callbackpath?view=aspnetcore-2.2

But does not say something more about that yet. I even don't know how to use it and I can't find any other tutorial about it.

Would you please tell me how can I invoke the callback? Thank you.

Comment: @alsami I just looked the source-code of that. It is a fully complete account system, all of them are OK. Whereas I am just a beginner, it is hard for me to get to know so much unknown code.

Comment: @alsami the website tutorial is just the same as Microsoft provides, not a full tutorial.

Comment: @alsami I want to debug it but I can't. Google has strict the callback URL must be a normal URL that registered in Google API Console but not a localhost URL.

Comment: That's not true, it can be localhost. I am using google apis for oauth as well.

Comment: _“Now the next step is the invoke the callback. However, I don't know how to invoke it after login.”_ – What do you mean with that?

Comment: @alsami When I login in not only the demo you provide but also I made myself. Google will throw an error that 'Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

The redirect URI in the request, http://localhost:51792/signin-google, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. To update the authorized redirect URIs, visit: '

Comment: @poke For example: after login in, I want to show some user info, such as username on the page. But how can I get this info and render it in the back-end?

Comment: @poke I just need an easy demo. For example, there is page A which only has a login button. After I clicked the button and login-in, it will redirect to page B which only shows the Username I login in.

Comment: Do you want to use ASP.NET Core Identity (i.e. do you need local user accounts), or do you just want to sign in with Google?

Comment: Just sign in with Google@poke

Comment: @102425074 yes, the full address must match the one u have permitted in the developer console of google. In this case http://localhost:51792/signin-google.

Answer (score 1):

You can use like below. Login user on External login method then get the result with confirmlogin method.

```cs
[HttpGet]
public async Task<object> ExternalLogin()
{
    string redirectUrl = "api/account/ConfirmLogin&Provider=Google";

    await AuthenticationProperties properties = 
    SignInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties("Google", redirectUrl);
  
    return new ChallengeResult(provider, properties);
}


[HttpGet]
public async Task ConfirmLoginAsync(string Provider)
{
   /*
     make your checks
   */

    Request.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(url);
}
```

Also you need to register your url  like :
[registerUrl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgwVQ.png)

I hope it helps.